# How can I tell why my question is getting close votes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have a question: [Why does ArrayList seriously outperform LinkedList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692448/why-does-arraylist-seriously-outperform-linkedlist) and it has received three close votes. It seems a perfectly reasonable question to me and, I thought, well asked. I'm trying to figure out why it drew close votes.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to find out unless the question is actually closed.

So, according to the answer, I could've clicked on the close link, but was afraid to for fear of voting to close my own question. This doesn't seem appropriately self-discoverable. Maybe something in hover text to explain or a ? for a help tag?

Comment: Your question seems more like opinion based but that's my assumption.

Comment: Since you have more than 250 reputation, [you can already see open/close votes caste in your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

Comment: Why did this question get downvoted? Did I misunderstand why we ask questions here?

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar How is asking how to see close votes opinion based? It had a very clear cut answer on what to click on.

Comment: it is a thoroughly unresearched question, based on a false premise that nobody can reverse-engineer.  What happened next is not pretty, it has the completely wrong answer selected and leaves [java] programmers with the very dangerous assumption that it is *only* 28% slower.  Do yourself and the [java] community a favor and do find out why LinkedList is so bad, there is a lot of reading material out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can click the link for close votes to see how many close votes have been cast for each reason.

In your case, all four have been voted for "unclear what you're asking".  Judging by the comments, it appears to revolve around your unsubstantiated claim about the LinkedList being faster than the ArrayList.

Comment: Weird. I attached documentation showing how I substantiated that claim.

Comment: @Thom, you didn't attach any documentation at all. You just _linked_ to a document you wrote.

Comment: @yivi How should I have attached it?

Comment: @Thom, your question needs to be self-contained. External links only provide **supplemental** information.

Comment: @yivi What should I have provided that I did not? I provided the results that I found and asked why. Then I posted the source code of my test so others could re-create the results. Why is everything else not supplemental information?

Comment: I also voted to close as *Unclear*. You need to explain *why* you think that `LinkedList` ought to have been faster than `ArrayList`.